# Fan blades of jet engine

Tags: aircraft

I recently watched video of rolls-royce jet engine manufacturing. There they showed that they measure frequency of each fan blade. Why they did so? What is need of it?

Comment: I think this is really a question for the [Engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) though you'll need more info to get an answer. They could be using ultrasound scattering to look for manufacturing defects, but without more info it's hard to say.

Comment: https://youtu.be/UazsDDFsS7Q                                link for rollsroyle video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stiff structures have the propensity to resonate - that is vibrate at specific frequencies. This includes the blades in a turboprop. Jet engines produce huge amounts of energy over a broad range of frequency, and the manufacturers need to make sure that components in the engine are not capable of concentrating that energy in an internal resonance.

They do this using specialized dynamic signal analyzers, accelerometers and impact hammers to gather vibration data and put together structural, modal models of the fan blade assembly. These can reveal asymmetrical modes in any of the fan blades and the possibility of concentrating energy and stress that could lead to failure under operation.

Comment: +1 And after all that, they fling a dead goose through it, with rather spectacular results http://bit.ly/2ckEnsC